# how to display my first array element in the page with an URL from this array

Tags: javascript, ajax, url

I'm a beginner don't be rude please : p

i got a question .
I got this request from my local API :

```
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200 || this.status == 201) {
        let cameras = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.table(cameras);
        let cameraList = document.getElementById('cameraList');
        cameras.forEach(camera => {
          cameraList.innerHTML += `
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img src="${camera.imageUrl}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${camera.name}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">${camera.description}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">${(camera.price / 100).toFixed(2)} EUR</p>
                    <a href="Product.html?id=${camera._id}" class="btn btn-primary">Détails</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                `;
        });

      }
    }

    request.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/api/cameras");
    request.send();
  </script>
```

and it's work perfectly .
[image: index.html]
i got 5 camera with img, name, description, price and ID  on my index.html page .
But now, when i click on the button Détails on my index.html i want to display the element who got the same ID that i defined in my loop Foreach.

For exemple here is the page with my first ID : .....Product.html?id=5be1ed3f1c9d44000030b061

Can you help me please ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You'll need to add an event listener to that Details button. Do you have code that currently does that?

Comment: what is/are the problems that you have encountered?

Comment: Why don't you use the new fetch API??